# X-Path Query issues

Tags: xml, xpath, dtd

My XML DTD is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE Bookstore [
<!ELEMENT Bookstore (Book | Magazine)*>
<!ELEMENT Book (Title, Authors, Remark?)>
<!ATTLIST Book ISBN CDATA #REQUIRED
              Price CDATA #REQUIRED
              Edition CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Magazine (Title)>
<!ATTLIST Magazine Month CDATA #REQUIRED Year CDATA #REQUIRED> 
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Authors (Author+)>
<!ELEMENT Remark (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Author (First_Name, Last_Name)>
<!ELEMENT First_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Last_Name (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

I want to run the following query:

```
Title Book whose title is the same as title of a magazine.
```

I cant think a way to run this query.Anyone Please help me with this i will b thanksful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
//Bookstore/Book/Title[. = //Magazine/Title]
```

Above xpath returns all `<Title>` elements that is child of `<Book>` and has value equals to at least one `<Title>` of `<Magazine>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following:

```
//Bookstore/Book[Title = ../Magazine/Title]/Title
```